# how to invite friends with restFB library?

Tags: java, facebook, libgdx, restfb

I want to build a platform independent fb app(libgdx) that will allow to invite friends. I have no knowledge about fb api so I stumbled upon the RestFB library. It looks like it can be used with libgdx.

I'm not really sure how to achieve the "invite friends" functionality with RestFB. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some more reading about facebook integration. It seems the RestFB library is only useful AFTER you get the authorization token(login).
Getting this authorization token in a platform independent way seems impossible so I will revert to using their SDKs for each platform(at least for login).